# Question about $\delta$'s in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

If a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at point $x_0$ we know that for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in M$ and $|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. Let's call those $\epsilon$ and $\delta(\epsilon)$ a pair, $(\epsilon,\delta)$.

What happens if I shrink the $\delta$? Does this imply that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ also shrinks?

My intuition says that we can't make any claim on the behaviour of $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$. Sure if $\delta$ attains a value which is very small then it will be smaller than another $\delta'$ which belongs to a pair $(\epsilon',\delta')$ where the $\epsilon'<\epsilon$. But if I shrink $\delta$ only a bit what happens then? How do I argue in a formal way?

Comment: Continuity means you can prove that GIVEN $\epsilon$, there EXISTS $\delta$.  No assertions are made about $\epsilon$ for a given $\delta$. (Nor can there be -- for instance, you can always choose $\delta$ smaller than "the" $\delta$, and the proof still holds.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens.

Continuity says that if you are given $\epsilon > 0$ then you can find $\delta > 0$ such that the following statement is true:

> $(*)$ if $|x-x_0| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

So, let's suppose that the $\epsilon$ has been chosen, and let's fix its value. And having done that, let's choose a value of $\delta$ which makes statement $(*)$ true. Then any smaller value will also make statement $(*)$ true. In other words, if $0 < \delta' < \delta$ and if $(*)$ is true then the following statement (obtained by substituting $\delta'$ in place of $\delta$) is also true:

> $(*')$ if $|x-x_0| < \delta'$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

The reason for this is that $|x-x_0| < \delta'$ and $\delta' < \delta$ together imply $|x-x_0| < \delta$.

Comment: If your answer to my question is "Nothing" then it is clearly wrong (consider the identity function). The rest of your answer doesn't adress my question.

Comment: Consider the identity function. For each $\epsilon > 0$, the statement $(*)$ is true with $\delta = \epsilon$, and it is also true for any smaller value $\delta' < \delta = \epsilon$ substituted in place of $\delta$. So, actually, my answer is correct for the identity function. Also, the rest of my answer does answer to your question, by showing that if you shrink $\delta$ then nothing happens: having fixed $\epsilon$, statement $(*)$ is true for $\delta$ and statement $(*)$ remains true with $\delta$ replaced by any shrunken value.

Comment: Perhaps you might be assisted better by the more succinct comment of @NickPeterson, but Nick and I are basically saying the same thing.

Comment: I have edited my question. What I had in my mind and what I actually wrote down were two different things. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

If you've not yet played around with what pairs delta and epsilon work, you might want to try something like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iejhw8zhqd which can give you a feel for what happens as you shrink delta.  The question you are asking is basically "if I narrow my x-window, does that necessarily shrink the y-window?" the answer could be yes or no, but depends on the behaviour of your function.  It might be instructive to try it for a function like f(x) = sin(1/x)  (with f(0) = 0) to test your intuition.

Comment: But regardless of the specific function, as long as it is continuous the difference $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ will eventually shrink if I choose a sufficiently small $\delta$. Is this right? And if it is right how do I prove it?

Comment: That's the definition of continuity - if you want to shrink |f(x) - f(x_0)| to say be less than .001 then continuity guarantees there's some delta that does this.  Same for .00001 or any positive epsilon.

Comment: But if I shrink the $\delta$ to $\delta'$ I can't be sure that this $\delta'$ is the one that also shrinks $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - in general delta' might not shrink the |f(x) - f(x_0)|.  it depends on what delta' you choose.

Comment: Maybe a quick example will help: 

In some proofs in our lecture the professor uses the following argument: let be $f$ continuous at point $x_0$, $A$ some expression, $M$ the supremum of $f$ on $[x,x_0]$ and $m$ the infimum of $f$ on $[x,x_0]$. Now consider that $m\leq A\leq M$ for all $x \in|x-x_0|<\delta$. Then the professor says that due to continuity if $x\to x_0\implies A=f(x_0)$. This gives the impression that shrinking $\delta$ will eventually shrink the difference $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$.

Comment: This is exactly correct - shrinking delta will indeed eventually shrink the difference.  How much it shrinks will depend on your purposes.  So if you want |f(x) - f(x_0)| < epsilon then you know there's some delta that will make this true.